# How to change page data without refresh using Django

Tags: sql-server, django, cryptocurrency

I am working on a project that shows live currency prices.  I have to refresh the pricing data on the page dynamically. In this project I am using Django and SQL server. I  could not figure out how to make it work using  triggers and AJAX because AJAX needs an event to run like a user event or timer (that very bad for performance).  Further,  triggers can not be processed by Django. Is there a way to do it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can write your ajax call in one function and use `setInterval` to run every second.

Comment: When DO you want to change the page data? If not a user action event or time-based event?

Comment: when data (insert, update, delete) in database

Comment: No, I said that timers are very bad for performance.

Comment: Look into using [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a popular package for that.

Comment: long polling with `intervals` or `django-channels`